# unable to understand an example from developer.mozilla.org

Tags: http

In the following tutorial https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications

There is an example (at the beginning)

```
<input type="file" id="input" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
```

Where does `this.files` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this.files is the objects that correspond to the files selected by the user.

Comment: so I don't define it. It is available to me, provided by HTML?

Comment: yes, ".this" refers to the Window object of the browser